# QT connect function using lambda

Tags: qt, lambda

I have a list with buttons , everyone has a name (str1 is the QString var with the name) and I want to connect them with a function with parameter but i don't understand how to do this.

```
 QPushButton *btn  = new QPushButton(str1);
 connect(btn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(activeProjectClick()));
```

this is what i can do but here i can't use function with parameter. I read that i have to use the connect method with lambda but i don't understand exactly how to do this. Let's supose i want to call function F1(QString str) , how can i do this?

Comment: `for(QPushButton *btn : buttonsList) { connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]({F1("Your string"); });}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but why i cannot use a variable name instead of "Your String"?

Comment: I figured out , i have to declare the var inside [] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `=` to capture by value or use '&' capture by reference.

```cpp
connect(btn,
        &QPushButton::clicked,
        this,
        [=]
        {
            F1(str1);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out , i have to declare the var inside []

alternatively, use `&` inside []

```
QString str;
for(QPushButton *btn : buttonsList) { connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]({F1(str); });}
```